# Change xtype dynamically according to the bind value in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am having a UI page which contains a table which shows the information and we are using extjs to ftech and show the values.

My code is below.

The component looks like below:

```
<item name="value1" xtype="link" bind="{value}">
    <position>22</position>
    <default>1</default>
    <displayable>1</displayable>
    <enabled>1</enabled>
    <exportable>1</exportable>
    <alwaysAvailable>1</alwaysAvailable>
    <editors>
        <editor name="filter" xtype="textfield"/>
    </editors>
    <events>
        <event name="click" jsFunction="onClickOpenScreen">
            <config>{"url":"......}}</config>
        </event>
    </events>
    <config>{"width": 100}</config>
</item>
```

and the model is :

```
<field name="value" tableAlias="table1" column="value" datatype="string">
    <required>0</required>
    <formula>if some value then value else 0</formula>
</field>
```

Here in the formula we are fetching the value from db, if value is there then value otherwise display 0.

So my requirement is if any value is there then that will come as hyperlink otherwise it will come as simple value. But from this code even 0 is coming as link.

Comment: This doesn't look like `extjs`, rather it looks like `ext.net`. Is this correct ?

Comment: this is exj js only...in xml form

Comment: I never saw this. Can you provide a link to documentation. ExtJs doc does not mention XML form, as far is I know.

Comment: It is not possible in ExtJS to change the `xtype` of a component.

Comment: @Alexander are you saying the requirement is not possible to do?

Comment: That depends on the requirement, which I don't understand completely from your description. [Your question is an X-Y question, sort of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Most people who asked how to change the xtype of a component wanted to switch between a textfield and a combo, which is doable, sort of, because it is a special case: you can instantiate xtype:'combo' and then configure the combo at runtime to act exactly like a textfield.